# Swift: Lazily encapsulating chains of map, filter, flatMap

Tags: swift, functional-programming, flatmap

I have a list of animals:

```
let animals = ["bear", "dog", "cat"]
```

And some ways to transform that list:

```
typealias Transform = (String) -> [String]

let containsA: Transform = { $0.contains("a") ? [$0] : [] }
let plural:    Transform = { [$0 + "s"] }
let double:    Transform = { [$0, $0] }
```

As a slight aside, these are analogous to filter (outputs 0 or 1 element), map (exactly 1 element) and flatmap (more than 1 element) respectively but defined in a uniform way so that they can be handled consistently.

I want to create a lazy iterator which applies an array of these transforms to the list of animals:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
  func transform(_ transforms: [Transform]) -> AnySequence<String> {

    return AnySequence<String> { () -> AnyIterator<String> in
      var iterator = self
        .lazy
        .flatMap(transforms[0])
        .flatMap(transforms[1])
        .flatMap(transforms[2])
        .makeIterator()

      return AnyIterator {
        return iterator.next()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which means I can lazily do:

```
let transformed = animals.transform([containsA, plural, double])
```

and to check the result:

```
print(Array(transformed))
```

I'm pleased with how succinct this is but clearly:

```
        .flatMap(transforms[0])
        .flatMap(transforms[1])
        .flatMap(transforms[2])
```

is an issue as it means the transform function will only work with an array of 3 transforms.

**Edit:**
I tried:

```
  var lazyCollection = self.lazy
  for transform in transforms {
    lazyCollection = lazyCollection.flatMap(transform) //Error
  }
  var iterator = lazyCollection.makeIterator()
```

but on the marked row I get error:

**Cannot assign value of type 'LazyCollection< FlattenCollection< LazyMapCollection< Array< String>, [String]>>>' to type 'LazyCollection< Array< String>>'**

which I understand because each time around the loop another flatmap is being added, so the type is changing.

How can I make the transform function work with an array of any number of transforms?

**One WET solution for a limited number of transforms would be (but YUK!)**

```
  switch transforms.count {
  case 1:
    var iterator = self
      .lazy
      .flatMap(transforms[0])
      .makeIterator()
    return AnyIterator {
      return iterator.next()
    }
  case 2:
    var iterator = self
      .lazy
      .flatMap(transforms[0])
      .flatMap(transforms[1])
      .makeIterator()
    return AnyIterator {
      return iterator.next()
    }
  case 3:
    var iterator = self
      .lazy
      .flatMap(transforms[0])
      .flatMap(transforms[1])
      .flatMap(transforms[2])
      .makeIterator()
    return AnyIterator {
      return iterator.next()
    }
  default:
    fatalError(" Too many transforms!")
  }
```

**Whole code:**

```
let animals = ["bear", "dog", "cat"]

typealias Transform = (String) -> [String]

let containsA: Transform = { $0.contains("a") ? [$0] : [] }
let plural:    Transform = { [$0 + "s"] }
let double:    Transform = { [$0, $0] }

extension Array where Element == String {
  func transform(_ transforms: [Transform]) -> AnySequence<String> {

    return AnySequence<String> { () -> AnyIterator<String> in
      var iterator = self
        .lazy
        .flatMap(transforms[0])
        .flatMap(transforms[1])
        .flatMap(transforms[2])
        .makeIterator()

      return AnyIterator {
        return iterator.next()
      }
    }
  }
}

let transformed = animals.transform([containsA, plural, double])

print(Array(transformed))
```

Comment: can't you send the number of iterations ?

Comment: transforms.count ?

Comment: As you say I know the number of transforms as transforms.count but I can't see how to use that to make a loop of ".flatMap" operations because the type changes at each iteration.

Comment: i can see, the problem is this type as far as i know "iterator" can't take bounds to as it needs to implement directly the way you did, but some workaround can be applied by sending a flag to use another iterator or something.

Comment: I'm wondering about changing the title of the question to: "Swift: Lazily encapsulating chains of map, filter, flatMap" as I think that would describe the essence of what this question is about much better but wondering if it's considered bad form to change the title of a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach to achieve what you want:

> **Edit**: I tried:
>
> ```
> var lazyCollection = self.lazy
> for transform in transforms {
>     lazyCollection = lazyCollection.flatMap(transform) //Error
> }
> var iterator = lazyCollection.makeIterator()
> ```

You were very near to your goal, if the both types in the *Error* line was assignable, your code would have worked.

A little modification:

```
var lazySequence = AnySequence(self.lazy)
for transform in transforms {
    lazySequence = AnySequence(lazySequence.flatMap(transform))
}
var iterator = lazySequence.makeIterator()
```

Or you can use `reduce` here:

```
var transformedSequence = transforms.reduce(AnySequence(self.lazy)) {sequence, transform in
    AnySequence(sequence.flatMap(transform))
}
var iterator = transformedSequence.makeIterator()
```

Whole code would be:

(**EDIT** Modified to include the suggestions from Martin R.)

```
let animals = ["bear", "dog", "cat"]

typealias Transform<Element> = (Element) -> [Element]

let containsA: Transform<String> = { $0.contains("a") ? [$0] : [] }
let plural:    Transform<String> = { [$0 + "s"] }
let double:    Transform<String> = { [$0, $0] }

extension Sequence {
    func transform(_ transforms: [Transform<Element>]) -> AnySequence<Element> {
        return transforms.reduce(AnySequence(self)) {sequence, transform in
            AnySequence(sequence.lazy.flatMap(transform))
        }
    }
}

let transformed = animals.transform([containsA, plural, double])

print(Array(transformed))
```

Comment: Very nice! – Minor remarks: The initial value in reduce can be `AnySequence(self)`, without the `lazy`. On the other hand, `AnySequence(sequence.lazy.flatMap(transform))` would avoid the creation of intermediate arrays.

Comment: Nice suggestion, frankly I had been forgotten that `flatMap` on `Sequence` generates an intermediate array. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks so much Martin and OOPer.  Your combined thought have given me an elegant solution. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can apply the transformations recursively if you define the method on the `Sequence` protocol (instead of `Array`). Also the constraint `where Element == String` is not needed if the transformations parameter is defined as an array of `(Element) -> [Element]`.

```
extension Sequence {
    func transform(_ transforms: [(Element) -> [Element]]) -> AnySequence<Element> {
        if transforms.isEmpty {
            return AnySequence(self)
        } else {
            return lazy.flatMap(transforms[0]).transform(Array(transforms[1...]))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about fully taking this into the functional world? For example using (dynamic) chains of function calls, like `filter(containsA) | map(plural) | flatMap(double)`.

With a little bit of reusable generic code we can achieve some nice stuff.

Let's start with promoting some sequence and lazy sequence operations to free functions:

```swift
func lazy<S: Sequence>(_ arr: S) -> LazySequence<S> {
    return arr.lazy
}

func filter<S: Sequence>(_ isIncluded: @escaping (S.Element) throws -> Bool) -> (S) throws -> [S.Element] {
    return { try $0.filter(isIncluded) }
}

func filter<L: LazySequenceProtocol>(_ isIncluded: @escaping (L.Elements.Element) -> Bool) -> (L) -> LazyFilterSequence<L.Elements> {
    return { $0.filter(isIncluded) }
}

func map<S: Sequence, T>(_ transform: @escaping (S.Element) throws -> T) -> (S) throws -> [T] {
    return { try $0.map(transform) }
}

func map<L: LazySequenceProtocol, T>(_ transform: @escaping (L.Elements.Element) -> T) -> (L) -> LazyMapSequence<L.Elements, T> {
    return { $0.map(transform) }
}

func flatMap<S: Sequence, T: Sequence>(_ transform: @escaping (S.Element) throws -> T) -> (S) throws -> [T.Element] {
    return { try $0.flatMap(transform) }
}

func flatMap<L: LazySequenceProtocol, S: Sequence>(_ transform: @escaping (L.Elements.Element) -> S) -> (L) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<L.Elements, S>>> {
    return { $0.flatMap(transform) }
}
```

Note that the lazy sequences counterparts are more verbose that the regular `Sequence` ones, but this is due to the verbosity of `LazySequenceProtocol` methods.

With the above we can create generic functions that receive arrays and return arrays, and this type of functions are extremely fitted for pipelining, so let's define a pipeline operator:

```swift
func |<T, U>(_ arg: T, _ f: (T) -> U) -> U {
    return f(arg)
}
```

Now all we need is to feed something to these functions, but to achieve this we'll need a little bit of tweaking over the `Transform` type:

```swift
typealias Transform<T, U> = (T) -> U

let containsA: Transform<String, Bool> = { $0.contains("a") }
let plural:    Transform<String, String> = { $0 + "s" }
let double:    Transform<String, [String]> = { [$0, $0] }
```

With all the above in place, things get easy and clear:

```swift
let animals = ["bear", "dog", "cat"]
let newAnimals = lazy(animals) | filter(containsA) | map(plural) | flatMap(double)
print(Array(newAnimals)) // ["bears", "bears", "cats", "cats"]
```

Comment: Wow! Very nice @Cristik.  When I first started thinking about this I did wonder if there might be a way to create an operator to combine filter, map, flatMap but have only been exploring functional thinking for a couple of months so my brain couldn't fathom it - so great to see your methods.  One thing that isn't clear to me... how would I access the result lazily?

let operation = filter(containsA) | map(plural) | flatMap(double)
for x in operation(animals) {
  print(x)
}  is not lazy?

Comment: @Adahus good question, the laziness in this approach doesn't seem to function that well so I updated the answer and removed the `lazy` calls since they seem to help with almost nothing. I'll try and get back with a really "lazy" solution :)

Comment: I'm wondering if the free functions need to be passing AnySequence?

Comment: @Adahus actually, I was able to solve the problem via protocols only, I updated the answer and now if you provide a lazy sequence as a starting point then the whole pipeline will be lazy.

Comment: Wow again!  This is awesome.  Thanks for putting in the time to write this.  Even though this isn't many lines of code it represents quite a significant set of methods.  My next challenge is to ponder how to allow a lazy cartesian product to be added to the pipeline...

Comment: Just discovered https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-overture which is similar territory. (I have no connection with Pointfree.)