# Swift Problem with Composing Lazy Sequence Transforms

Tags: swift, functional-programming, lazy-sequences

I'm continuing my foray into functional swift and very much enjoying the challenge.
I'm working with Transforms which turn elements into lazy sequences.

To state the error up front, I'm getting:
Cannot convert value of type
'Transform' (aka '(Int) -> LazySequence>')
to expected argument type
'(*) -> LazySequence<[*]>'

My problem is with composing them but I need to give some context to show the issue.

Here's the Transform:

```
typealias Transform<T, U> = (T) -> LazySequence<[U]>
```

And I can define Forward Application:

```
precedencegroup LazyForwardApplication {
  associativity: left
}

infix operator |~>: LazyForwardApplication

func |~> <T: LazySequenceProtocol, U>(
  input: T,
  transform: @escaping Transform<T.Elements.Element,U>
  ) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<T.Elements, LazySequence<[U]>>>> {

  return input.flatMap(transform)
}
```

The return type is a bit of a mouthful but it works fine:

```
let start = [10,20,30].lazy

let add4_5_6: Transform<Int, Int> = {
  let result = [ $0 + 4, $0 + 5, $0 + 6]
  print("> add4_5_6(\($0)) -> \(result)")
  return result.lazy
}
```

// Note that I put the debug in partly so I can be sure that it's happening lazily.

```
let result1 = start |~> add4_5_6
result1.forEach{ print($0) }
// 14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 34, 35, 36
```

And another similar example:

```
let add7000_8000: Transform<Int, Int> = {
  let result = [ $0 + 7000, $0 + 8000]
  print("> add7000_8000(\($0)) -> \(result)")
  return result.lazy
}

let result2 = start |~> add7000_8000
result2.forEach{ print($0) }
// 7010, 8010, 7020, 8020, 7030, 8030
```

And I can chain these together inline:

```
// Double application
let result3 = start |~> add4_5_6 |~> add7000_8000
result3.forEach{ print($0) }
// 7014, 8014, 7015, 8015, 7016, 8016,
// 7024, 8024, 7025, 8025, 7026, 8026,
// 7034, 8034, 7035, 8035, 7036, 8036
```

But I'd like to be able to compose them too:

```
// Forward Composition
precedencegroup LazyForwardComposition {
  associativity: right
}
infix operator >~>: LazyForwardComposition

func >~> <T, U: Sequence, V: Sequence>(
  left:  @escaping Transform<T,U>,
  right: @escaping Transform<U,V>
  ) -> (T) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<[U], LazySequence<[V]>>>> {

  return { input in
    let b: LazySequence<[U]> = left(input)
    let c = b.flatMap(right)
    return c
  }
}
```

And here's where I get an error:

```
let composed = add4_5_6 >~> add7000_8000
// ERROR IN ABOVE LINE: Cannot convert value of type
'Transform<Int, Int>' (aka '(Int) -> LazySequence<Array<Int>>')
to expected argument type
'(_) -> LazySequence<[_]>'

let result4 = start |~> composed
result4.forEach{ print($0) }
```

The result would come out the same as result3

I've worked round this a few times but keep getting stuck.
Any thoughts on how to resolve appreciated.

(My previous question is similar territory but a different issue:
[Swift: Lazily encapsulating chains of map, filter, flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386361/swift-lazily-encapsulating-chains-of-map-filter-flatmap/54393138?noredirect=1#comment95625701_54393138)
)

**For a playground:**

```
typealias Transform<T, U> = (T) -> LazySequence<[U]>

// And I can define Forward Application:

precedencegroup LazyForwardApplication {
  associativity: left
}

infix operator |~>: LazyForwardApplication

func |~> <T: LazySequenceProtocol, U>(
  input: T,
  transform: @escaping Transform<T.Elements.Element,U>
  ) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<T.Elements, LazySequence<[U]>>>> {

  return input.flatMap(transform)
}

// The return type is a bit of a mouthful but it works fine:

let start = [10,20,30].lazy

let add4_5_6: Transform<Int, Int> = {
  let result = [ $0 + 4, $0 + 5, $0 + 6]
  print("> add4_5_6(\($0)) -> \(result)")
  return result.lazy
}

// Note that I put the debug in partly so I can be sure that it's happening lazily.

let result1 = start |~> add4_5_6
result1.forEach{ print($0) }
// 14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 34, 35, 36

// And another similar example:

let add7000_8000: Transform<Int, Int> = {
  let result = [ $0 + 7000, $0 + 8000]
  print("> add7000_8000(\($0)) -> \(result)")
  return result.lazy
}

let result2 = start |~> add7000_8000
result2.forEach{ print($0) }
// 7010, 8010, 7020, 8020, 7030, 8030

// And I can chain these together inline: 

// Double application
let result3 = start |~> add4_5_6 |~> add7000_8000
result3.forEach{ print($0) }
// 7014, 8014, 7015, 8015, 7016, 8016,
// 7024, 8024, 7025, 8025, 7026, 8026,
// 7034, 8034, 7035, 8035, 7036, 8036

// But I'd like to be able to compose them too:

// Forward Composition
precedencegroup LazyForwardComposition {
  associativity: right
}
infix operator >~>: LazyForwardComposition

func >~> <T, U: Sequence, V: Sequence>(
  left:  @escaping Transform<T,U>,
  right: @escaping Transform<U,V>
  ) -> (T) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<[U], LazySequence<[V]>>>> {

  return { input in
    let b: LazySequence<[U]> = left(input)
    let c = b.flatMap(right)
    return c
  }
}

// And here's where I get an error:

let composed = add4_5_6 >~> add7000_8000
// ERROR IN ABOVE LINE: Cannot convert value of type 'Transform<Int, Int>' (aka '(Int) -> LazySequence<Array<Int>>') to expected argument type '(_) -> LazySequence<[_]>'

let result4 = start |~> composed
result4.forEach{ print($0) }

// The result would come out the same as result3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer, but maybe it can help you get somewhere.

First of all, `Transform<T, U>` is defined as `(T) -> LazySequence<[U]>`, so `U` and `V` generic types can not be specialized as a `Sequence`:

```
func >~> <T, U, V>(
    left:  @escaping Transform<T,U>,
    right: @escaping Transform<U,V>
    ) -> (T) -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<[U], LazySequence<[V]>>>> {

    return { input in
        let b = left(input)
        let c = b.flatMap(right)
        return c
    }
}
```

Second, your `|~>` operator accepts a `Transform` as a right hand parameter, so you can not use it with the return type of the `>~>` parameter. I was able to get the result with the following line:

```
let result4 = start.flatMap(composed)
```

You could probably overload the `|~>` operator to accept the correct type, but it would not look nice. Or maybe it would, with enough typealiasing :)

Comment: Thanks, @pckill.  I can see why the Sequence specialization needs removing and your other comments useful.  I'll post back when I work this out.